# FLVPlayback component and Actionscript. Random Flv playback with Arrays.

Tags: actionscript-3

I have come a little closer with my project, and still need some help please. I have 5 Flvs which i want to play randomly on this page www.music-puppets.com/

The .fla file I have created contains this code:

```
var files:Array = [ "Sz01Puppet.flv", "Sz02Puppet.flv", "Sz03Puppet.flv", "Sz04Puppet.flv", "Sz05Puppet.flv" ];
var shuffledFiles:Array = shuffleArray(files);
//quick test
var testTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
testTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,updateFile);
testTimer.start();

function updateFile(event:TimerEvent):void{
if(shuffledFiles.length == 0) shuffledFiles = shuffleArray(files); //all files played, repeat process
trace('play file',shuffledFiles[0]);
shuffledFiles.shift();
}
function shuffleArray(source:Array,clone:Boolean = true):Array {
var output:Array = [];
var input:Array = clone ? [].concat(source) : source; //clone ? preserve orignal items by making a copy for shuffling, or not
while(input.length) output.push(input.splice(int(Math.random() * input.length-1),1) [0]);
return output;

}
```

This script works. In the Output every flv is listed randomly, and then repeated. Next up i want this AS Script to work with an FLV Component.

But how to I get that to work?

In my library I have the 5 flvs, and flvplayback component. 
I dragged the FLVPlayback component to the stage, but I can only add one flv in the source. How do I get my working actionscript to work with the FLVPlayback component.

Here you can see how my screen looks like.

[capture01.jpg](http://i1.creativecow.net/u/213313/capture01.jpg)

[capture02.jpg](http://i1.creativecow.net/u/213313/capture02.jpg)

Would be great to get some feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to give your FLVPlayback component an instance name using the properties panel.  That will let you talk to it from the code.

Next you will need to add a listener to the FLVPlayback component to detect when each video finishes.  Let's assume you've given it an instance name of `myVideo`:

```
myVideo.addEventListener(VideoEvent.COMPLETE,onVideoComplete);
```

You will need a handler function for this, and that will look similar to the function you currently use for each iteration of your timer:

```
function onVideoComplete(event:VideoEvent):void {
    if(shuffledFiles.length == 0) shuffledFiles = shuffleArray(files); //all files played, repeat process
    myVideo.source = shuffledFiles.shift(); //grab the first array item to play in the FLVPlayback component
}
```

Finally, make sure that your FLVPlayback component is set to play a new source automatically, then assign the first video to get things going:

```
myVideo.autoPlay = true;
myVideo.source = shuffledFiles.shift();
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested. I have got the running code :)

```
import flash.events.Event;
import fl.video.*;

var files:Array;
var shuffledFiles:Array;

loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,ready);
function ready(event:Event):void{
    loaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,ready);
    //swf rescale setup
    stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
    stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
    stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE,stageResized);
    //get FlashVars - a string converted into an Array by spliting it on the , character
    //if the files FlashVar is setup correctly use the data, else use default values
    if(loaderInfo.parameters.files != undefined) files = loaderInfo.parameters.files.indexOf(',') > 0 ? loaderInfo.parameters.files.split(",") : [loaderInfo.parameters.files];
    else files = [ "Sz01Puppet.flv", "Sz02Puppet.flv", "Sz03Puppet.flv", "Sz04Puppet.flv", "Sz05Puppet.flv" ];
    shuffledFiles = shuffleArray(files);
    //play the 1st video
    videoPlayer.source = shuffledFiles[0];
    shuffledFiles.shift();

    //see when the video finished playing
    videoPlayer.addEventListener(VideoEvent.COMPLETE,videoFinished);
}
function videoFinished(event:VideoEvent):void{
    if(shuffledFiles.length == 0) shuffledFiles = shuffleArray(files);//all files played, repeat process
    videoPlayer.source = shuffledFiles[0];//play the first video in the random list
    videoPlayer.play();
    trace('playing',shuffledFiles[0]);

    shuffledFiles.shift();//remove the first video from the random list (e.g. [2,0,1].shift() becomes [0,1])
}
function stageResized(event:Event):void{
    videoPlayer.width = stage.stageWidth;
    videoPlayer.height = stage.stageHeight;
}
function shuffleArray(source:Array,clone:Boolean = true):Array {
    var output:Array = [];
    var input:Array = clone ? [].concat(source) : source;//clone ? preserve orignal items by making a copy for shuffling, or not
    while(input.length) output.push(input.splice(int(Math.random() * input.length-1),1)[0]);
    return output;
}
```